# ADODB vb.net ComboBox value to Textbox working on the last index only

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox, textbox, adodb

I'm having a problem here in vb.net where I need to get the value of the combobox value to textbox. but it only shows the last index of the combobox. /

//here is my code

```
Private Sub cboname_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboname.SelectedIndexChanged
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCashier WHERE ProductCode= '" & cboname.Text & "' "

    Do Until myRecord.EOF
        txtname.Text = myRecord.Fields("Product").Value
        myRecord.MoveNext()
    Loop



    Call executeQuery2(strSql)
    Call getRecord()
End Sub
```

// ADODB CONNECTIONS

```
 Dim strSql As String
Dim myRecord As New ADODB.Recordset
```

// COMBO BOX VALUES

```
 Sub fillcombo()
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCashier"

    Do While Not myRecord.EOF
        cboname.Items.Add(myRecord.Fields("ProductCode").Value)
        myRecord.MoveNext()
    Loop

    cboname.Refresh()
    Call executeQuery(strSql)
    Call getRecord()
End Sub
```

// FORM_LOAD

```
  Private Sub myPOS_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call openConnection()
    Call getRecord()
    Call fillcombo()


End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using ADODB in the first place? Why aren't you using ADO.NET? What you should be doing is using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and then binding that to both the `ComboBox` and the `TextBox`. You then don't need any code to populate the `TextBox` as the user selects items.

Comment: As for the specific issue, given that you have a loop in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler that specifically moves to the end of the `Recordset`, why would you expect anything other than getting the last item?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing should be done something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SQL query here", "connection string here")
        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(table)

        BindingSource1.DataSource = table

        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "ColumnNameToDisplay"
            .ValueMember = "PrimaryKeyColumnName"
            .DataSource = BindingSource1
        End With

        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "OtherColumnNameToDisplay")
    End Using
End Sub
```

The `TextBox` will then automatically update as the selection in the `ComboBox` changes.